# Create HANDLE to BITMAP

Tags: winapi

Is there any way to create HANDLE (specifically HBITMAP) to existing in memory BITMAP struct without using Device Contex(DC)?

Comment: [`CreateDIBSection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183494%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: But this function requires HDC as attribute!

Comment: As an argument, not as attribute. And this argument may be NULL, or if even not NULL, it is not used for anything else but to create the bitmap.

Comment: OK, thx for info. I read MSDN on it and there was no annotation that this argument can be null, or __in_opt in function declaration - this why I got confused.

Comment: Many GDI functions accept a NULL `HDC` and treat it as the equivalent of calling `GetDc(0)` to get the screen `HDC`.